What is the max voltage I can apply to an electromagnet?
I have a small Amazon Electromagnet 4 ohms of resistance and wound with 110 feet of 28 AWG lacquered wire.  What is the maximum sustained voltage I can put through it?

We don't know, there's not enough information to be able to answer.

If you have a variable power supply, determine it experimentally. Raise the voltage until it is too hot to touch. It will take 5 minutes or so to stabilize, so you need to wait about that long at each voltage.

As a general rule, in coil and transformer windings, you don't want to have a wire cross-sectional area of less than 700-1000 "circular mils"1 per ampere. Since AWG 28 only has an area of 160 circular mils, you're going to want to limit the continuous current to no more than 160-230 mA.
If the total resistance is 4 Ω2, then the voltage should be no more than 0.64 to 0.92 V.

1 "Circular mils" is just the diameter (in mils) squared. An old standard way of rating wire.
2 That sounds a little low. 110 feet of AWG28 should be more like 7 Ω, giving you a voltage range of 1.12 to 1.61 V.

It's important to note that this is just a rule of thumb, and there may be reasons--mostly thermal--to allow more current or limit it to lower.
